Space of plane cubics though (a certain arrangement of) 8 points is a subspace of the space of all plane cubics paramaterisable by $\mathbb{P}^1.$
Exercise 4.2 of Hulek's Elementary Algebraic Geometry is as follows: Let $P_1,...,P_8$ be points in $\mathbb{P}^2$ such that no four of these points lie on a line and no seven lie on a conic. Show that the space of plane cubics through $P_1,...,P_8$ defines a subspace of all plane cubics which can be paramaterised by $\mathbb{P}^1.$
My initial thinking is: Let $[a_{ijk}]$ denote the coefficients for a cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2.$ If $p = [\alpha,\beta,\gamma] \in \mathbb{P}^2$ then the conic with coefficients $[a_{ijk}]$ passes through $p$ if and only if $$a_{3,0,0}\alpha^3 + a_{2,1,0}\alpha^2\beta + \cdots + a_{0,0,3}\gamma^3=0.$$ Note that $$\mathbb{V}(a_{3,0,0}\alpha^3 + a_{2,1,0}\alpha^2\beta + \cdots + a_{0,0,3}\gamma^3)$$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^9_{[a_{ijk}]}.$ So (hopefully) we can use $(\mathbb{P}^9_{[a_{ijk}]})^*$ to simplify this problem, however I am unable to proceede.

Well, you have the condition in terms of the coefficients of the cubic to pass through one point. What happens when you enforce this condition for all of your points? What does that get you in terms of cutting out a set of points in $\Bbb P^9$?

@KReiser Then, I will have the intersection of 8 hyperplanes which, if all points 8 do not lie on a line, I think gives me a $\mathbb{P}^1.$ Am I going wrong? Where do I use the fact that no four of these points lie on a line and no seven lie on a conic?

You'll have an intersection of 8 hyperplanes, but you'll need to do a bit more work to show that the intersection of these eight hyperplanes is only a $\Bbb P^1$, and that extra work is where you use the assumptions on the configurations of the points. See my answer below.

The condition that each point $P_i$ is on the cubic gives a linear condition on the space of coefficients, so the locus of cubics through $P_1,\cdots,P_8$ is the intersection of 8 hyperplanes in the $\Bbb P^9$ parametrizing plane cubics. To show that the intersection is actually a $\Bbb P^1$, we'll need to show that the space of cubics through $P_1,\cdots,P_n$ for $n<8$ has at least one cubic which doesn't pass through $P_{n+1}$, since this implies that the set of cubics passing through $P_1,\cdots,P_n$ is not contained in the hyperplane of cubics passing through $P_{n+1}$.
It suffices to prove this for $n=7$, since if $n<7$ we could just throw in some dummy points and pad $n$ up to $7$. I'd recommend giving it a try yourself before looking at the argument below - you'll need to do some explicit geometric reasoning with configurations of lines and conics through the $P_i$ using the assumptions that no 4 points are collinear and no 7 points are coconic, and I think it's worth working through a bit on your own before reading the answer.

 Let $n=7$, and for $i\in \{5,6,7\}$ let $C_i$ be the union of the conic $Q_i$ through $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_i$ and the line $L_{jk}$ through $P_j$ and $P_k$ where $\{j,k\}=\{5,6,7\}\setminus\{i\}$. I claim at least one of the $C_i$ does not contain $P_8$.


 If $P_8\in L_{56}$, then $P_8\notin L_{57}, L_{56}$, else $P_5,P_6,P_7,P_8$ would be collinear. So at the cost of allowing $P_8\in C_7$, we may assume that $P_8\notin L_{57},L_{67}$ and show $P_8$ is not on at least one of $Q_5$ or $Q_6$.


 Consider a conic $Q$ through $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_8$: if $P_8$ is on $Q_i$, then $Q_i\cap Q$ has at least 5 points, so by Bezout $Q_i$ and $Q$ share an irreducible component. If $Q$ is irreducible and $P_8$ is on $Q_5$ and $Q_6$, then $Q_5=Q_6=Q$, so $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6,P_8$ are co-conic, contradiction.


 On the other hand, if $P_8$ is on both $Q_5$ and $Q_6$ while $Q$ is reducible, then up to relabeling, we can write $Q$ as the union of the lines $L_{123}$ and $L_{48}$ (through $P_1,P_2,P_3$ and $P_4,P_8$ respectively), or the union of the lines $L_{128}$ and $L_{34}$ through ($P_1,P_2,P_8$ and $P_3,P_4$ respectively). In the first case, $Q_5 = L_{123} \cup L_{45}$ and $Q_6=L_{123}\cup L_{46}$, so since $P_8$ is not collinear with $P_1,P_2,P_3$, we must have $P_8$ on $L_{45}$ and $L_{46}$, giving $P_4,P_5,P_6,P_8$ collinear, contradiction. In the second case, $Q_5 = L_{12}\cup L_{345}$ and $Q_6 = L_{12} \cup L_{346}$, giving that $P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6$ are collinear, contradiction.

